# Run ipython/jupyter notebook server on aws ec2 without an ssh client

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ipython, jupyter

I can set up a ipython/jupyter notebook server on aws ec2 by following this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20160212170536/http://yangjie.me/2015/08/26/Run-Jupyter-Notebook-Server-on-Amazon-EC2/), it starts the remote server by entering `$jupyter notebook` in the local terminal.

However I also saw a pre-configured community AMI [graphlab-create](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-west-2#LaunchInstanceWizard:ami=ami-b4fb37d4), which will run the remote server without the need of a Linux/Unix ssh client at all.

I'm wondering how that could be realized, since some students may not have an access to a linux/unix system. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: You may want to have a look at jupyterhub: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterhub

Answer (score 1):

Using windows is not an issue. I hooked up to my notebook in AWS from my home computer. I have Windows 10.

You can link up to AWS using [putty](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html).

I am using a Ubuntu AMI.

Once you have a terminal open you simply follow the instruction you gave in [your link](http://yangjie.me/2015/08/26/Run-Jupyter-Notebook-Server-on-AWS-EC2/)

It worked like a charm for me.

Comment: This is a nice workaround. Thank you. But I am still wondering what the magic is behind that community AMI with which the server will run by itself once you click the 'start'.